# Python fork process inside Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, fork

I am running the following code inside a Jupyter notebook:

```
import os

print("Start")
pid = os.fork()

if pid == 0:
    print("Child")
    os._exit(os.EX_OK)
else:
    print("Parent")
    
if pid != 0:
    # parent
    pid, status = os.waitpid(pid, 0)
    print("Done")
```

I am getting the following output "almost" every time:

> Child
> Start
> Parent
> Done

How is it that "Child" gets printed before "Start"? Almost 9 out of 10 times, I get the output as above. Occasionally, I find what is intuitively expected ("Start" being printed first, followed by "Parent" or "Child" and then finally ending with "Done").

When I run the same code directly on the console, I get the expected outcome each time:

> Start
> Parent
> Child
> Done

Why do we see this peculiar behavior within Jupyter notebooks? And how to avoid this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like stdout is block buffered, not line buffered. The parent "Start\n" is waiting in the output buffer. The child "Child\n" starts out in its own output buffer but is flushed on exit. You could verify with `import sys;print(sys.stdout.isatty())`. The solution is to flush often

```
print("Start", flush=True)
```

or if you have multiple things to print,

```
print("Foo")
print("Bar")
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: Your solution certainly fixed the ordering for me! Thanks a lot :-)
I am going to test if this problem is retricted to printing.

Comment: It will depend on how its run. I don't use jupyter often, so I'm not sure. But if its done via `%run`, it may just be a piped subprocess so stdout would be block buffered.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment there is no way to avoid this that I know. Maybe there is a setting that is enabled. You could also try to add a wait. Before you print child or parent, etc. Hopefully this helps a bit.

Sleep like this:

```
import time
 
# Wait for 5 seconds
time.sleep(5)
 
# Wait for 300 milliseconds
# .3 can also be used
time.sleep(.300)
```

I would suggest waiting like .5 milliseconds to 1 second

Comment: Could you show me what you suggest by adding wait? Also wouldn't this be too arbitrary based on case to case about how much delay we apply.

Comment: Thanks for youre reply. I hope there is some other way to overcome this issue, as the use of timers is very "hacky". (That said, if nobody else is able to provide with a more straightforward solution, I will resort to this). Thanks.